# Flight changed after Schengen visa received and number of days increased

Tags: air-travel

Originally while applying fir the visa I said I would reach Rome on 17th May morning and exit from Paris to Mumbai on June 3. But Qatar Airlines cancelled hence I had to book Emirates.

I am travelling from Mumbai to Rome on 16th May and reaching on that day late evening. I'll exit from Paris to Mumbai on June 4 with Emirates.

I received a Swiss Schengen visa, multiple-entry, with a duration validity from May 12 2024 for 30 days, valid for 3 months.

At the time of the application, since I had given Qatar Airlines details, my stay was Italy - 6 nights, Switzerland - 8 nights and France - 3 nights.

Now due to the flight change, my stay is changed: Italy - 7 nights, Switzerland - 8 nights and France - 4 nights.

It's my first time travelling to Europe with my family.

I would appreciate if someone can tell me whether there will be any issue, since the itinerary was changed a little bit.

Comment: Your visa is valid for the extended duration, and this is hardly even a change (notably it doesn't change which country you'll stay in longest, so it can't even be argued that you should have applied somewhere else) that is relevant with respect to your visa. I don't think anybody will care, but bring a print of Qatar's cancellation for good measure.

Answer (score 6):

You're fine. Your new itinerary is well within the validity period of the visa.

If you use a Schengen visa in a significantly different way than the plans you described in the application, you can run into problems. In particular, if you enter a different Schengen country than you'd planned, you can definitely expect questioning. They want to make sure that you didn't deceive them about the purpose of your visit.

In this case, though, there's nothing especially suspicious. Flight changes happen all the time, and your new plans are basically the same as your old plans, just adjusted to compensate for the new flights. You *may* get asked about it, but it *won't* be a problem. If you're worried, make sure to bring the new itinerary, and the message from Qatar about the original flight cancellation.